# Javascript comparison not working on button with HTML entities in name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML

```
<button id="the_button" onclick="clicked()">&darr; Source &darr;</button>
```

Javascript

```
function clicked() {
    if ($("#the_button").html() == "&darr; Source &darr;") {
        alert($("#the_button").html());
    }
}
```

With the above code, I don't get an alert popup...

However, if I change the button text and the comparison string to just be `Source` without the HTML entities, it works:

HTML

```
<button id="the_button" onclick="clicked()">Source</button>
```

Javascript

```
function clicked() {
    if ($("#the_button").html() == "Source") {
        alert($("#the_button").html());
    }
}
```

Is there a way to have it work with the HTML entities `&darr;`?

Comment: Does it work if you compare to `"\u2193 Source \u2193"`?

Comment: In any case, it would be much more robust to use something like a class on the `<button>` to identify it. Relying on the text will break if somebody comes along and decides to alter it in the future.

Comment: It's a bit suboptimal design, but if you don't want to deal with html entities, wrap the arrows and the text 'Source' in 3 spans and only check the html of the middle one that contains 'Source'. I'm assuming you'll have more than one button using the 'clicked()' function as a handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe JS sees the entity and not the reference. Try using the unicode character reference of the DOWN ARROW (`\u2193`).

```js
var $btn = $( '#the_button' );

$btn.on( 'click', function () {

  var html = $btn.html(); // or .text()
  
  if ( '\u2193 Source \u2193' === html ) {
   alert( html );
  }
  
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="the_button">&darr; Source &darr;</button>
```

Helpful reference: [Unicode Table](https://unicode-table.com/en/) (provides Unicode and HTML references).

Answer (score 2):

This should work :

```
function clicked() {
    if ($("#the_button").html() == '\u2193 Source \u2193') {
        alert($("#the_button").html());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use fake element aswell

```
function clicked() {
    if ($("#the_button").text() === $('<span>&darr; Source &darr;</span>').text()) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the link http://www.ascii-code.com/html-symbol.php to know the ascii code for the Entity name.
see the link for https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes for how to use the escape sequence.

```js
function clicked() {
    if (document.getElementById("the_button").innerHTML == " \u2193 Source \u2193") {
        alert(document.getElementById("the_button").innerHTML);   
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="the_button" onclick="clicked()"> &darr; Source &darr;</button>
```